# Retrieve response content using powershell when server returns status code 400

Tags: web-services, powershell

So I'm calling a rest web service via powershell which responds with a 400 status code if you try to post data which has already been processed, along with the status code it also returns a JSON response in along the lines of:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "errorCode": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "validation failed",
    "developerMessage": " MessageId-xxx already processed. No Need to process again."
}
```

So I try calling this with some powershell and receive the 400 status code and handle this using try/catch to get the exception, but there is no content in the response, I can get the response headers, status code, status message etc, but I cannot find a way to access the JSON response at all, here is the format of the powershell code I'm using:

```
$url = "https://example.com/webservice/status"
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\certthumbprintxxxxx
$headers = @{"tokenId" = "tokenxxxxx"}

$body = 
@"
{
...
 JSON data...
...
}
"@

try 
{
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Certificate $cert -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body
    }
catch
{
    $_.Exception.response
    }
```

When I send `$_.Exception.response` to Get-Member I can see that there is no content property.  How can I access the message in the response using powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the content message from ErrorDetails Property via `$_.ErrorDetails.Message`. It returns a string.

As an alternative you can also directly read the stream from WebResponse class using `$_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609194/how-to-process-webresponse-when-net-throws-webexception-400-bad-request), I had to put the stream to position 0 again as it seems to already have been read by powershell)

```
   $s = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
   $s.Position = 0;
   $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($s)
   $err = $sr.ReadToEnd()
   $sr.Close()
   $s.Close()
```

Comment: Brilliant, cheers, just a note is that in my case $_.ErrorDetails.Message was null, so I didn't get anything from there, directly reading the response stream worked a treat though.  Thanks.